# Defining parameters by some transformation OR Retaining sub-graphs, but not the whole graph

Tags: python, pytorch, autograd

I'm coming across an issue I haven't seen come up before. I work in Bayesian Machine Learning and as such make a lot of use of the distributions in PyTorch. One common thing to do is to define some of the parameters of distributions in terms of the log of their parameter, so that in optimisation they cannot go negative (e.g. the standard deviation of a Normal distribution).

In order to be distribution independent however, I do not want to have to manually recompute the conversion of this parameter. To demonstrate via example:

The following code will NOT run. After the first backward pass, the part of the graph the calculates the exponential of the parameter is automatically removed, and not re-added.

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.distributions as dd

log_std = nn.Parameter(torch.Tensor([1])) # Define the log of the parameter as an nn.Parameter, this is what we want to optimise
std = torch.exp(log_std) # Define the transformation we want to apply to the parameter to using it in the distribution
mean = nn.Parameter(torch.Tensor([1])) # A normal parameter
dist = dd.Normal(loc=mean, scale=std) # Define the distribution. From here I want to ONLY refer to this, not the other variables

optim = torch.optim.SGD([log_std, mean], lr=0.01) # Standard optimiser
target = dd.Normal(5,5) # Target distribution to match

for i in range(50):
    optim.zero_grad()

    samples = dist.rsample((1000,)) # Sample our model, note no reference to log_std

    cost = -(target.log_prob(samples) - dist.log_prob(samples)).sum() # KLdivergence cost metric
    cost.backward()
    optim.step()
    print(i)
    print(log_std, mean, cost)
    print()
```

The next set of code WILL run, but I must explicitly reference the `log_std` parameter in the loop, and recreate the distribution. If I wanted to change the distribution type, it would not be possible without considering the specific case.

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.distributions as dd

log_std = nn.Parameter(torch.Tensor([1])) # Define the log of the parameter as an nn.Parameter, this is what we want to optimise
mean = nn.Parameter(torch.Tensor([1])) # A normal parameter

optim = torch.optim.SGD([log_std, mean], lr=0.001) # Standard optimiser
target = dd.Normal(5,5) # Target distribution to match

for i in range(50):
    optim.zero_grad()

    std = torch.exp(log_std)  # Define the transformation we want to apply to the parameter to using it in the distribution
    dist = dd.Normal(loc=mean, scale=std)  # Define the distribution.

    samples = dist.rsample((1000,)) # Sample our model, note no reference to log_std

    cost = -(target.log_prob(samples) - dist.log_prob(samples)).sum() # KL divergence cost metric
    cost.backward()
    optim.step()
    print(i)
    print(mean, std, cost)
    print()
```

The first example does however work in Tensorflow, as the graphs there are static. Does anyone have some ideas on how I might fix this? If it were possible to keep only the part of the graph that defines the relationship `std = torch.exp(log_std)` then this could work. I have also tried playing with backwards gradient hooks, but unfortunately to calculate the new gradient properly you need access to the parameter value and the learning rate.

Thanks in advance!
Michael

**EDIT**

I have been asked for an example of how I might want to change the distribution. Taking the code which currently will NOT work, and changing the distributions to Gamma distributions:

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.distributions as dd

log_rate = nn.Parameter(torch.Tensor([1])) # Define the log of the parameter as an nn.Parameter, this is what we want to optimise
rate = torch.exp(log_std) # Define the transformation we want to apply to the parameter to usi it in the distribution
concentration = nn.Parameter(torch.Tensor([1])) # A normal parameter
dist = dd.Gamma(concentration=concentration, rate=std) # Define the distribution. From here I want to ONLY refer to this, not the other variables

optim = torch.optim.SGD([log_rate, concentration], lr=0.01) # Standard optimiser
target = dd.Gamma(5,5) # Target distribution to match

for i in range(50):
    optim.zero_grad()

    samples = dist.rsample((1000,)) # Sample our model, note no reference to log_std

    cost = -(target.log_prob(samples) - dist.log_prob(samples)).sum() # KL divergence cost metric
    cost.backward()
    optim.step()
    print(i)
    print(log_std, mean, cost)
    print()
```

Looking at the code that currently works however:

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.distributions as dd

log_rate = nn.Parameter(torch.Tensor([1])) # Define the log of the parameter as an nn.Parameter, this is what we want to optimise
mean = nn.Parameter(torch.Tensor([1])) # A normal parameter

optim = torch.optim.SGD([log_rate, concentration], lr=0.001) # Standard optimiser
target = dd.Gamma(5,5) # Target distribution to match

for i in range(50):
    optim.zero_grad()

    rate = torch.exp(log_rate)  # Define the transformation we want to apply to the parameter to usi it in the distribution
    dist = dd.Gamma(concentration=concentration, rate=rate)  # Define the distribution.

    samples = dist.rsample((1000,)) # Sample our model, note no reference to log_std

    cost = -(target.log_prob(samples) - dist.log_prob(samples)).sum() # KL divergence cost metric
    cost.backward()
    optim.step()
    print(i)
    print(mean, std, cost)
    print()
```

And you see we have to change the code inside the loop to allow the algorithm to work. Its not a big issue in this small example, but this is just a demonstration for much larger algorithms where it would be incredibly beneficial to not have to worry about

Comment: could you make an example of how you would change the distribution type? I think I understood it but I want to be sure before posting an answer

Comment: @iacolippo I've added in some examples for you, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The easy fix is adding `retain_graph=True` to `cost.backward()`.

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.distributions as dd

log_std = nn.Parameter(torch.Tensor([1])) # Define the log of the parameter as an nn.Parameter, this is what we want to optimise
std = torch.exp(log_std) # Define the transformation we want to apply to the parameter to using it in the distribution
mean = nn.Parameter(torch.Tensor([1])) # A normal parameter
dist = dd.Normal(loc=mean, scale=std) # Define the distribution. From here I want to ONLY refer to this, not the other variables

optim = torch.optim.SGD([log_std, mean], lr=0.01) # Standard optimiser
target = dd.Normal(5,5) # Target distribution to match

for i in range(50):
    optim.zero_grad()

    samples = dist.rsample((1000,)) # Sample our model, note no reference to log_std

    cost = -(target.log_prob(samples) - dist.log_prob(samples)).sum() # KLdivergence cost metric
    cost.backward(retain_graph=True)
    optim.step()
    print(i, log_std, mean, cost)
```

You can free part of the graphs with `del <variable name>`, for example `del cost` will delete the part of the graph to compute `cost`.

The optimal solution would be to detach `samples` from the parameters of the distribution. Unfortunately I haven't found a way to do that, `.detach()` doesn't seem to work when dealing with outputs of `.rsample()`.

Comment: Thank you. I have tried both these - unfortunately I don't want to keep the whole graph as this can lead to large memory errors, and for the sake of generality I don't want to have to manually delete everything except the specific parts I want to keep. If there is an automatic way to do that however that would be really helpful.

Detaching the samples from the parameters of the distribution I does not, I think, achieve what I want (you can just use '.sample()' to do this) as I need the gradients to flow through the samples, as it is the parameters of the distribution I'm trying to train.

Comment: Yes, I understand the concern about memory. I think that if you put the computational graph of the inner loop in a function, then you would only needto delete the output of the function, but I'm not sure. For `detach`, I had something a bit different in mind: split the computational graph in two and manually feed the grad of the second part to the first, using `retain_graph=True` only for the first part. I have posted a question with the example [here](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/detach-rsamples-from-distributions-parameters/50251?u=iacolippo)